# How to run a Python plugin on QGIS startup

Tags: python, qgis-plugins

I am new to QGIS and Python plugin development. Is there any way to execute a Python plugin when QGIS starts up? I read startup.py file can be used. What method should I try?

Comment: Check this gitlab page : https://madmanwoo.gitlab.io/foss4g-python-workshop/startup/.